# Is there a way to generate a deeper outline view than eclipse does?

Tags: java, spring, stack-trace

[Outline view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KntOo.png)
I'd like to get the methods that these methods call and so on.

For example getApplications() -> service.findAll() ->repository.findAll() etc until it ends (including split paths).

Kind of like a stack trace but without actually running the code.

It doesn't have to be via eclipse, if some plugin/library can run through the code and generate it that would work too.

Eclipse outline view is the closest I've found till now

Comment: Eclipse also has a call hierarchy view...

Comment: Yes, but I think that's bottom up, I'm looking for something top down. Like the methods the method is using, not where the method is being used.

Comment: It can also be switched to callee hierarchy, see https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-call-hierarchy.htm

Comment: Ahh perfect didn't know that. Is there a way to do it on a class level instead of a method by method basis?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm sure there are plugins for this, but asking for tool recommendations is off-topic on this site.